# regex multiple replaces in one go using c++ regex

Tags: c++, regex

I want use C++ regex class  to turn

```
SELECT TableOne.ColumnOne, TableOne.@ColumnTwo, TableOne.ColumnThree FROM TableOne WHERE TableOne.@ColumnTwo ='abc'
```

into

```
SELECT TableOne.ColumnOne, TableOne.ColumnThree FROM TableOne WHERE TableOne.ColumnTwo ='abc'
```

basically, want to do the following

(1)remove anything like "TableOne.@ColumnTwo" before "FROM"

(2)remove any "@" after "FROM"

could someone please shed me some light? there does not seem a direct two to do all these in on go.

Comment: I didn't understand what to replace to what.

Comment: He basically wants to remove `@`. I don't see the difficulty of this task ...

Comment: no. please take a closer look. want to get rid of TableOne.@ColumnTwo, before FROM and get rid of @ after WHERE

Comment: @hongpei ok, you should next time really specify and show what you have tried. [Here's](http://regex101.com/r/bK2gK9) how you could do it.

Answer (score 0):

## Description

Regex: `^(.*?)TableOne[.]@ColumnTwo,\s+(.*?)[@](.*?)$`  Replace with: `\1\2\3`

[image]

## Example

This is C# example is added to show how the regex works.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace myapp
{
  class Class1
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          String sourcestring = "SELECT TableOne.ColumnOne, TableOne.@ColumnTwo, TableOne.ColumnThree FROM TableOne WHERE TableOne.@ColumnTwo ='abc'";
          String matchpattern = @"^(.*?)TableOne[.]@ColumnTwo,\s+(.*?)[@](.*?)$";
          String replacementpattern = @"\1\2\3";
          Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(sourcestring,matchpattern,replacementpattern,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline));
        }
    }
}

$sourcestring after replacement:
SELECT TableOne.ColumnOne, TableOne.ColumnThree FROM TableOne WHERE TableOne.ColumnTwo ='abc'
```